# converting PDF as Image with PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, phantomjs

Im working with PhantomJs to convert webpages as images, and that works fine, here is my code to do that

```
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://myurl.com/mypage/ out_put_image.png
```

This works very well, but when I load an URL locating any PDF, this is unable to take screenshot of that PDF and giving error as "Unable to load the address!"
my code goes like

```
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://myurl/myfolder/mypdf.pdf pdf_image.png
```

Phantom is unable to do this :(

Is there any way to achieve this? or with any other JS/PHP frameworks to do this?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1):

wget and ImageMagick can be used to do this.

```
wget 'http://myurl/myfolder/mypdf.pdf'
convert mypdf.pdf -append pdf_image.png
```

Comment: the question is about using phantomjs

Comment: @PatrikLaszlo, the end of the question suggests Phantom cannot solve the problem and asks for alternative approaches.
"Phantom is unable to do this :(. Is there any way to achieve this? or with any other JS/PHP frameworks to do this?"